# Does there exist an application of independent $\sigma$-algebras outside of probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

The notion of [stochastic (mutual) independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_random_variables) is encoded by the notion that the cumulative distribution function of the intersection of events is equal to the product of the marginal cumulative distribution functions.

However, generalizing from a probability measure to an arbitrary measure quickly shows that the notion could, in principle, be applied to other measure spaces (See [Definition E.4.1](http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/E_4.html) for a generically-stated definition).

Has this more general, possibly non-statistical, notion of independence been used elsewhere in applied mathematics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the notion of independence really only makes sense on probability spaces.  Let $(\Omega,\mu)$ be a general non-signed measure space with two non-trivial independent $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal F, \mathcal G$.  By independence, since $\Omega \in \mathcal F$ and $\Omega \in \mathcal G$, we have $$\mu(\Omega) = \mu(\Omega \cap \Omega) = \mu(\Omega) \cdot \mu(\Omega).$$  This implies either $\mu(\Omega) = 0$, in which case the measure is trivial, or $\mu(\Omega) = 1$ in which case $(\Omega,\mu)$ is a probability space.

Comment: The question asks whether or not there are applications of independence outside probability theory, not outside of probability spaces.  One can do measure theory in a probability space without really doing probability theory in spirit.  This answer seems too final to me.